# Wix installer - using the same property for reading from the registry and setting during the UI

Tags: installation, wix

I Have a (simple) wix project. In the project, I have a property which gets it's value from the registry (if such registry key exists). 
On a dialog, the user sees the value of that property and then can change it.
For some reason, I cannot see that the property gets the value from the registry...
Will appreciate your help:

from the wix project:

```
<!-- The Registry group of the installation package. -->
<ComponentGroup Id="RegistryGroup">     
  <Component Id="_70B15100_F11D_48BF_8349_3E3B83157C54" Guid="2F344400-5C37-4CAE-902E-7100FDD2DB22" Transitive="no" Directory="TARGETDIR">
    <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\YYY" ForceCreateOnInstall="no" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="no">

      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ServerPort" Value="[SERVERPORT]" />
      <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="ServerAddress" Value="[SERVERADDRESS]" />

    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
<!-- The composite feature of the installation package. -->
<Feature Id="CompleteInstall" Title="All Files" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="FileSystemGroup" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="RegistryGroup" />
</Feature>
<Upgrade Id="{D627BB25-59CB-4387-AF42-0127AC701DBE}">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="3.11.7" Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="no" Language="1033" />
  <UpgradeVersion Maximum="3.11.7" Property="OLDPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="no" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" Language="1033" />
</Upgrade>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CA_CreateConfig" Sequence="1" />
  <Custom Action="DIRCA_TARGETDIR" Before="CostInitialize"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = ""]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts"><![CDATA[NEWPRODUCTFOUND]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_C976A2F6_5EC5_4EE5_898C_4A660FC42C9F.Commit.SetProperty" After="StartServices"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_C976A2F6_5EC5_4EE5_898C_4A660FC42C9F.Commit" After="_C976A2F6_5EC5_4EE5_898C_4A660FC42C9F.Commit.SetProperty"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_458FD9FC_2B2B_45E5_B89F_E5C67FA1AB86.Install.SetProperty" After="_C976A2F6_5EC5_4EE5_898C_4A660FC42C9F.Commit"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_458FD9FC_2B2B_45E5_B89F_E5C67FA1AB86.Install" After="_458FD9FC_2B2B_45E5_B89F_E5C67FA1AB86.Install.SetProperty"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_854AE351_70ED_4318_82B0_B079EDD6C3CD.Rollback.SetProperty" After="_458FD9FC_2B2B_45E5_B89F_E5C67FA1AB86.Install"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_854AE351_70ED_4318_82B0_B079EDD6C3CD.Rollback" After="_854AE351_70ED_4318_82B0_B079EDD6C3CD.Rollback.SetProperty"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769>2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_BEF9A9A6_06F8_43FA_85B9_F40521FCC587.Uninstall.SetProperty" After="MsiUnpublishAssemblies"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769=2]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="_BEF9A9A6_06F8_43FA_85B9_F40521FCC587.Uninstall" After="_BEF9A9A6_06F8_43FA_85B9_F40521FCC587.Uninstall.SetProperty"><![CDATA[(NOT DISABLESERVICE) AND $com_DCAB0809_69B4_442E_82E5_E600A7E1E769=2]]></Custom>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1" Sequence="701" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT2" Sequence="702" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT3" Sequence="703" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT4" Sequence="704" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="ERRCA_UIANDADVERTISED" Sequence="5"><![CDATA[ProductState=1]]></Custom>
  <AppSearch Sequence="100" />
  <FindRelatedProducts Sequence="200" />
  <LaunchConditions Sequence="400"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></LaunchConditions>
  <CCPSearch Sequence="500"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></CCPSearch>
  <RMCCPSearch Sequence="600"><![CDATA[NOT Installed]]></RMCCPSearch>
  <ValidateProductID Sequence="700" />
  <Custom Action="DIRCA_TARGETDIR" Before="CostInitialize"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = ""]]></Custom>
  <Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts"><![CDATA[NEWPRODUCTFOUND]]></Custom>
  <CostInitialize Sequence="800" />
  <FileCost Sequence="900" />
  <IsolateComponents Sequence="950"><![CDATA[RedirectedDllSupport]]></IsolateComponents>
  <CostFinalize Sequence="1000" />
  <ExecuteAction Sequence="1300" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1" Sequence="701" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT2" Sequence="702" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT3" Sequence="703" />
  <Custom Action="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT4" Sequence="704" />
  <Show Dialog="CustomTextA" Sequence="1001"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND NOT RESUME]]></Show>
  <Show Dialog="ProgressForm" Sequence="1299" />
  <Show Dialog="FatalErrorForm" OnExit="error"><![CDATA[NOT HideFatalErrorForm]]></Show>
  <Show Dialog="UserExitForm" OnExit="cancel" />
  <Show Dialog="FinishedForm" OnExit="success" />
  <Custom Action="VSDCA_FolderForm_AllUsers" Sequence="997"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND NOT RESUME AND ALLUSERS=1]]></Custom>
  <Show Dialog="ResumeForm" Sequence="998"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND RESUME]]></Show>
  <Show Dialog="MaintenanceForm" Sequence="999"><![CDATA[Installed<>""]]></Show>
</InstallUISequence>
<AdminUISequence>
  <Custom Action="DIRCA_TARGETDIR" Before="CostInitialize"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = ""]]></Custom>
  <CostInitialize Sequence="800" />
  <FileCost Sequence="900" />
  <CostFinalize Sequence="1000" />
  <ExecuteAction Sequence="1300" />
  <Show Dialog="AdminWelcomeForm" Sequence="1001"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND NOT RESUME]]></Show>
  <Show Dialog="AdminProgressForm" Sequence="1299" />
  <Show Dialog="AdminFatalErrorForm" OnExit="error" />
  <Show Dialog="AdminUserExitForm" OnExit="cancel" />
  <Show Dialog="AdminFinishedForm" OnExit="success" />
  <Show Dialog="AdminResumeForm" Sequence="998"><![CDATA[Installed="" AND RESUME]]></Show>
  <Show Dialog="AdminMaintenanceForm" Sequence="999"><![CDATA[Installed<>""]]></Show>
</AdminUISequence>
<UI Id="Base">
  <Error Id="1001">Error [1]. [2]</Error>
  <Property Id="VSDNETURLMSG" Value="This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?" />
  <Property Id="VSDIISMSG" Value="This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again." />
  <Property Id="VSDUIANDADVERTISED" Value="This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic." />
  <Property Id="VSDNETMSG" Value="This setup requires the .NET Framework version [1].  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again." />
  <Property Id="VSDINVALIDURLMSG" Value="The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager." />
  <Property Id="VSDVERSIONMSG" Value="Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed." />
</UI>

<CustomAction Id="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT1" Property="SERVERADDRESS" Value="[SERVERADDRESS]" Execute="firstSequence" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT2" Property="SERVERPORT" Value="[SERVERPORT]" Execute="firstSequence" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT3" Property="EDITA3" Value="" Execute="firstSequence" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomTextA_SetProperty_EDIT4" Property="EDITA4" Value="" Execute="firstSequence" />
<CustomAction Id="VSDCA_FolderForm_AllUsers" Property="FolderForm_AllUsers" Value="ALL" />
<CustomAction Id="ERRCA_UIANDADVERTISED" Error="[VSDUIANDADVERTISED]" />
<Property Id="CustomTextA_NextArgs" Value="EulaForm" />
<Property Id="EulaForm_PrevArgs" Value="CustomTextA" />
<Property Id="EulaForm_NextArgs" Value="WelcomeForm" />
<Property Id="WelcomeForm_PrevArgs" Value="EulaForm" />
<Property Id="WelcomeForm_NextArgs" Value="ConfirmInstallForm" />
<Property Id="ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs" Value="WelcomeForm" />
<UI Id="CustomText1Dlg">
  <Dialog Id="CustomTextA" X="50" Y="50" Width="373" Height="287" Title="[ProductName]">
    <Control Id="NextButton" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="261" Width="66" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;Next &gt;" TabSkip="no" Default="yes">
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[CustomTextA_NextArgs=""]]></Publish>
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="[CustomTextA_NextArgs]"><![CDATA[CustomTextA_NextArgs<>""]]></Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Label1" Type="Text" X="18" Y="108" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Server Address (leave empty for default)" TabSkip="no" />
    <Control Id="Edit1" Type="Edit" X="18" Y="120" Width="348" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" TabSkip="no" Property="SERVERADDRESS" Sunken="yes" />
    <Control Id="Label2" Type="Text" X="18" Y="144" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Server Port (leave empty for default)" TabSkip="no" />
    <Control Id="Edit2" Type="Edit" X="18" Y="156" Width="348" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" TabSkip="no" Property="SERVERPORT" Sunken="yes" />
    <Control Id="Label3" Type="Text" X="18" Y="180" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Edit3:" Hidden="yes" TabSkip="no" />
    <Control Id="Edit3" Type="Edit" X="18" Y="192" Width="348" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" TabSkip="no" Property="EDITA3" Hidden="yes" Sunken="yes" />
    <Control Id="Label4" Type="Text" X="18" Y="216" Width="348" Height="12" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Edit4:" Hidden="yes" TabSkip="no" />
    <Control Id="Edit4" Type="Edit" X="18" Y="228" Width="348" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}" TabSkip="no" Property="EDITA4" Hidden="yes" Sunken="yes" />
    <Control Id="CancelButton" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="261" Width="66" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}Cancel" TabSkip="no" Cancel="yes">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="Cancel" />
    </Control>
    <Control Id="PreviousButton" Type="PushButton" X="228" Y="261" Width="66" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&lt; &amp;Back" TabSkip="no">
      <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[CustomTextA_PrevArgs=""]]></Condition>
      <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[CustomTextA_PrevArgs<>""]]></Condition>
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="[CustomTextA_PrevArgs]"><![CDATA[CustomTextA_PrevArgs<>""]]></Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerBmp" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="375" Height="52" Text="_bbb3a8b4c218495cb88ea30ee85d4499" TabSkip="no" Disabled="yes" />
    <Control Id="BodyText" Type="Text" X="9" Y="63" Width="354" Height="42" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}The installed agent will use the following connection properties." TabSkip="yes" NoPrefix="yes" />
    <Control Id="BannerText" Type="Text" X="9" Y="9" Width="306" Height="33" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0}Specify Connection Details" TabSkip="yes" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" />
    <Control Id="Control273" Type="Line" X="0" Y="252" Width="375" Height="6" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}MsiHorizontalLine" TabSkip="yes" Disabled="yes" />
    <Control Id="Control278" Type="Line" X="0" Y="52" Width="375" Height="6" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0}MsiHorizontalLine" TabSkip="yes" Disabled="yes" />
  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are getting the value of the property from the registry, but that requires a RegistrySearch element and there doesn't seem to be one in your WiX source.

Comment: I couldn't put the entire file so I only showed the relevant lines. The action exist

Comment: @Dafna You already copied a lot of that file! How could **this information** not be relevant?

Comment: The problem was that I used a tool that converted a vs project to a wix project and did it wrong adding extra unnecessary lines..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I used a tool that automatically converted my vdproj to a wix project. This conversion was not perfect and it created a custom action and a set property that I did not need. Once these were deleted, everything worked perfectly.